# Can all functions be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

After being introduced to the non-elementary function through an attempt to evaluate $\int x \tan (x)$, an interesting question occurred to me:
Can the non-elementary functions be decomposed to elementary ones?  For instance, the logarithm, an elementary, can be decomposed into multiplication (e.g. $\ln x=y$ is the same as $y$ iterations of $e*e$), another elementary.  So, is this decomposition possible to transform a complicated non-elementary function into an elementary one that can be easily evaluated?

Comment: Decomposed in what sense, exactly? What exactly do you mean by $y$ iterations of $e \times e$, in the case that $y$ is not an integer (or rational)?

Comment: Special functions can usually be defined with power series which is a decomposition to more elementary functions of sorts

Comment: The solution to the natural logarithm of some number $x$ is $e$ multiplied by itself some number of times $y$, I don't necessarily care about the rationality of that number or even if it is real or complex.  It still leads to a lower operation.  Another example of this principle would be $5*7$ being the same as $5+5, 7x$

Comment: What exactly is the solution to $\mathrm{ln}(x) = \pi$ in your scheme? How do you add $e$ $\pi$ times?

Comment: The fact that it produces an irrational result is irrelevant.  In theory, multiplication is addition, and a logarithm is solving for an exponent, which is in turn multiplication.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no general method of expressing arbitrary functions in terms of elementary ones. For the ones that we can express that way, it usually is not of much practical interest, as the distinction between elementary and non-elementary is mostly artificial.

Comment: But how do you multiply something by itself $\pi$ times? There is a way to formalize exponentiation through repeated iteration, but it has to be much more careful/precise than what's detailed here (continuous continuation). Besides, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

No. Doesn't matter which logical language you try to use and the interpretation, number of function that can be defined using that language is at most the number of finite string that can be formed using the symbols of that language. Since symbols set is finite, number of possible string is countable. Number of function however is far from countable, it is actually $c^{c}$ for function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

(in other word, even if you have way more than just elementary function, there are function you simply cannot describe at all)

EDIT: thanks for the comments. In light of these, I will add a few more variant:

-If we allow the symbols set to be of cardinality $c$ (say, maybe we allow not just elementary function, but any continuous function), and restrict to only measurable function. Then this is still impossible by the counting argument. Unfortunately, restriction to measurable function does not decrease cardinality, and increasing the symbols set cardinality only give you the cardinality of possible sentence to be $c$.

-If we allow the symbol set to be of cardinality $\aleph_{0}$, and restrict to continuous function, then it is still impossible by counting argument. Continuous function have cardinality $c$, but number of possible string is still $\aleph_{0}$.

Comment: Well, I suppose OP would allow use of real parameters. In that case, you can define continuum many functions. Still far from $2^\mathfrak c$.

Comment: OK. Let's now restrict to *continuous* functions. The counting argument does not work anymore.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: it still work, since continuous function is still uncountable, while number of strings is countable only.

Comment: Constant functions are elementary, so you can generate $\mathfrak c$ functions this way.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: of course, that is only if we assume that we have enough symbols to actually specify any constant function we want to use. Anyway, if you allow symbol set to be cardinality $c$, and only continuous function, then I'm pretty sure every function can indeed by "described", so not just counting argument, but any argument against it will fail.

Comment: Not necessarily. That's what makes the question interesting. A natural interpretation is whether the closure of the set of elementary functions under compositions, differentiation, and integration is the set of all continuous functions. (The answer to this version is easy, as only analytic functions are obtained this way. Somewhat more challenging, not all analytic functions can be obtained this way.) There are of course other ways of formalizing the problem that allow various limiting processes as well.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: "closure" depend on the choice of topology. If we choose say, uniform metric, then the answer is well-known: the set of analytic function is closed under all the above operation (and arithmetic operation too), and is also a closed set under uniform metric, and contains all elementary functions. So the answer is still no.

Comment: (@Gina Uniform limits are too restrictive when working with analytic functions, since the domains are/may be open rather than compact. If we allow both closed and open domains, and closure under uniform limits, we *do* get all continuous functions, at least those with domain a bounded interval. The natural setting to stay within the analytic functions would be uniform convergence on compact sets. But this is getting off topic. My point was simply that there are interesting and natural ways of asking the question, beyond the very strict finitary approach that renders it trivial.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: it doesn't matter, since you can always look at just a finite interval (we are just trying to show that there are continuous function that is not in the closure). Anyway, I chose an interpretation that is likely to cover many interpretation of the vague idea of "decompose" that is also understandable to the asker (sound like the asker have never had analysis yet)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean a very general kind of "decomposition" in which you are allowed to rewrite the functions in terms of some procedure involving some sequence of "elementary" operations.

It seems to me that any "decomposition" in any reasonable sense would have to be capable of being described using a finite number of words and symbols. This would allow even procedures with an infinite number of steps converging on the answer, such as power series, as long as the *rules* for the procedure are finite.

It also seems reasonable that we can only have a fixed finite set of elementary operations to work with. Otherwise it's hard to see how they can all be elementary.

Given the possibility of writing any finite set of rules using a fixed finite set of operations, words, and symbols, there are only a countably infinite number of possible "decompositions" that can be written. (I'm assuming there is no limit on the *length* of a "decomposition"; if there were such a limit, the number of "decompositions" would be finite.)

But there are an uncountable number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, let alone functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore we cannot decompose all functions.

Comment: I don't understand your counting. Constant functions are elementary, and there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: I meant the ones you can write down. I can write the function $y = c$ in finite space for any constant $c$ that I can write in finite space, but there are real constants $c$ that I cannot write in finite space.

Comment: But this is not the question. At the very beginning, together with the exponential and logarithm, and other things, you have access in an idealized way to all constant functions. This is not a question about actual explicit computability of numbers.

Comment: Actually the original question said nothing about constant functions, and I'm not completely convinced the OP had in mind functions $y = c$ where we can't describe $c$ except as "some real constant", but that is an interesting point. The discussion of this under the answer by @Gina is better than I could muster.