# Proving the Cavalieri Principle using integrals (Calculus I)

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing some calculus I problems and I'm facing this one in [Stewart's Calculus book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1285740629):

Page 448 problem 65(a)

> Cavalieri's Principle states that if a family of parallel planes gives
>   equal cross-sectional areas for two solids $S_1$ and $S_2$, then the
>   volumes of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equal. Prove this principle.

My solution is the same I saw in a solution manual found on internet:

[image]

I don't think it's right because we can't guarantee the existence of a integrable function $A(z)$ or even a description of a function using elementary functions and operations (like polynomial, rational, trig functions, etc.) See this answer: [Can all functions be expressed in terms of elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849093/can-all-functions-be-expressed-in-terms-of-elementary-functions)

So I think we are both wrong (myself and the solution manual). I think this is something a calculus first year student wouldn't never realised.

Comment: If $A(z)$ cannot be "described", you cannot tell that it is the same for both solids.

Comment: @GCab exactly. So this proof is incorrect?

Comment: I think it depends on what is referred to as a solid here. Considering a solid being somehow **space bounded** and the volume being a continuous sum of positive & finite areas $A(z)$, one can be assured that the integral converges as increasing and bounded by $height*sup(A(z))$ - the very existence of such function A(z) being implied by the exercise- . Maybe you are expecting a more formal answer but I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: @Jeanba you answered perfectly. I think the book should have said about these requirements in order to make the proof work. These kind of sloppy questions make students create some misconceptions which are sometimes difficult to remove.

Comment: Ok thanks, glad this was useful. I just converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what is referred to as a solid here. Considering a solid being somehow **space bounded** and the volume being a continuous sum of positive & finite areas $A(z)$, one can be assured that the integral converges as increasing and bounded by $height*sup(A(z))$ - the very existence of such function A(z) being implied by the exercise- .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to prove the Cavalieri Principle without using this assumption in its more general form?

Comment: by "this assumption" you are referring to the space bounded one?

Comment: If the solid is not space bounded, I would guess it imposes A(z) being bounded anyways as it makes little sense to declare stricto sensu two infinite areas being equal. An interesting case of study to start could be the Gabriel's horn to see what minimum conditions are necessary on A(z) in order to get a as general as possible Cavalieri's principle. I think a finite number of Infinite A(z) could be a good candidate.

Comment: Insteresting, thank you!